# How do you assign a custom DNS name to a Windows Azure Web Role?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I am hosting a website using a web role in windows azure, but I am not able to figure out how to configure the domain name. I set up a Azure Website (different than Web Role) earlier this week, and I had to modify the CNAME with my domain name provider and then configure the site in the windows azure web portal. For the web role, I have pointed my domain name provider to the correct IP address, but I can't seem to configure my web role to accept this name. All I get when I visit the page from the new domain name is a 404 error. Visiting the site from the .cloudapp.net address works as expected.

Do you need do configure something in the web portal, or is there some way to configure this in the cloud project config?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Cloud Service (web/worker), you should just need to set up a CNAME to map www to `yoursite.cloudapp.net`. And you also need to forward the root domain (e.g. `yoursitename.com`) to `www.yoursitename.com`.

You can also use A records. See [this page](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns/) for more details, for both CNAME and A record.

Comment: You are correct. It turns out I just hadn't waited long enough for the DNS to refresh. Everything seems to be working as expected now.